# Powermethod (Eigenvalue problems)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I don't really get it, when the method converges..

The formula I have says that if the eigenvalue with the greatest absolute value has the algebraic multiplicity of 1, and is strictly greater than all other eigenvalues, which means if:

|lambda 1| > |lambda 2| >= |lambda 3| >= .... >= |lambda n|

then the method converges.

And if there are many eigenvalues with the same greatest absolute value, then xi can loop between 2 eigenvectors and not converge.

Now, I have this matrix:

[image: matrix A]

And I'm trying to iterate with the Rayleigh-Quotient-method, which is based on the power method, with starting value x_0 = (1, 0) and assumed eigenvalue near lambda_0 = 4.

I end up after 2nd iteration with lambda_2 = 5.0583
and x_2 = (0.4759, 0.8795)

And 3rd iteration with lambda_3 = 4.99999 and x_3 = (-0.4475, -15.495)

if I try the 4th iteration with these values, I get x_4 = (-0.4472, -0.8943) and lambda_4 = 4.999889.

What can I say about:
1) the convergence?
2) the absolute value greatest eigenvalue?
3) the eigenvector?

It seems that it's converging to Eigenvalue = 5, and eigenvector x = (-0.4472, -0.8943). Is it right or I'm wrong?

Thank you so much for any hints! I am really confused!

Comment: You can verify it yourself. Multiply x with matrix. How much does it differ from 5x?

Answer (score 1):

> What can I say about: 1) the convergence?

It converges when there is a dominant eigenvalue. It has trouble converging when they are very close together, which isn't the case here.

> 2) the absolute value
>   greatest eigenvalue?

The matrix is small so you can check it by hand.

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $$

then

$$ \det(A- \lambda I) = \det(\begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2 \\ 4 & 3-\lambda \end{pmatrix}) = (1-\lambda)(3-\lambda) - 8  =\lambda^{2} - 4 \lambda - 5  $$

Then

$$ \lambda^{2} - 4\lambda  -5 = (\lambda +1)(\lambda-5) \implies \lambda_{1} = 5 , \lambda_{2} = -1$$

> 3) the eigenvector?

To get the eigenvector we plug that in

$$  A-5 I = \begin{pmatrix}  -4 & 2 \\ 4 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then we have that $v_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$
so

$$ q_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix}$$

I created a small program for this...

```
import  numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2],[4,3]])
xk = np.array([[1],[0]])


def iterate(A,x):
    rho = np.dot(A,x)
    #lambda_i
    nk = np.max(np.absolute(rho))
    # v_i
    xk = 1/nk* rho

    return rho, nk, xk

n = 55

for i in range(n):
    if (i % 5 == 0):
        rho, nk, xk = iterate(A,xk)
        print("The {i}'th lambda iterate is:{lambda_i}".format(i=i+1,lambda_i =nk))
        print("The {i}'th eig_vec iterate is:{vec_i}".format(i=i+1,vec_i =xk))
```

If you use it, you should have

$$ x_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{4} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ x_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} .5625 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ x_{3} = \begin{pmatrix} .4880 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ x_{3} = \begin{pmatrix} .5024 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ x_{4} = \begin{pmatrix} .49952 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ x_{5} = \begin{pmatrix} .50009 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

after 50 iterations you'll have

$$ x_{50} =\begin{pmatrix} .5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$

or

$$ v_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Thank you for your help!! 1) what is v1 and what is q1? Is v1 the eigenvector to lambda_1? 2) But this is not using the power method. I have to use the power method to determine the absolute value greatest eigenvalue and the eigenvector. Clarifying my question 1: convergence: I mean is the power method converging or diverging?

Comment: I'll change (add to) this one moment. $v_{1}$ is the solution you get but isn't orthonormal.

Comment: Thanks so much!! and q1 is the eigenvector, right? Im writing my last exam in my degree, and this chapter is very important and confuses me a lot! Many thanks for your support here!!

Comment: And I think you mean sqrt(5) not sqrt(3), right?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: it doesn't make sense for you to see if it converges using the Rayleigh quotient for the power method however this should converge. The rayleigh quotient method iteratively changes some parameter so you don't converge slowly. You're asking if it converges and you have 4 iterations and it is less than like 1/10000 from the value?

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot!! But I mean how to do it with that method? Im I doing it right when you read my values?

Comment: How did you get the values you have above then?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBiQh1vsCLU you can follow this...do you want me to write it by hand?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Shogun89/cdadfb78d33fd0a4c73f23bcdf67cdfe

Comment: If you do this by hand by like iteration 3 or 4 the arithmetic is dumb so you can just plug it in.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers and the Python code! Can you just add lambda_i values with the x_i's? I am not sure if my method calculating lambdas is right. Just to verify I'm doing the right thing! Thx again!